# How should Google Analytics 4 be used with react native application?

Tags: react-native, google-analytics, firebase-analytics, google-analytics-4

We have a website, and a react-native based iOS and Android apps that present that website in a mobile app (with push notifications). If we have the website send the messages through a single G- measurement id, in GA dashboard it shows web as the platform 100% of the time. Is the best way to manage the platform value to create multiple streams? We have different apps for different audiences, so it would be hard to maintain that many new multiple streams for each app. Is there a way to populate Platform in a different way?

I see when we are in the app, the browser value is like Safari (in-app) or Android Webview. But that doesn't tell us app or if the website is in a social media app. I am thinking the best way to proceed is to make a custom dimension for knowing if the user is inside the app. Is that the best way forward for us?

Comment: I just work with the web version, and as long as I am concerned in GA4 you can create your stream based on web, iOS and/or Android.  So, you may have 3 different streams and 3 different Measure Ids. If I were in you, I would create 3 various streams and if you need more info which is not provided by the predefined events, you can create custom dimensions.

Comment: Where you able to add this?